# How to get a public variable (in a Module) to NOT share value between users

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, module, scope

I'm working in an ASP.NET (VB) Web Application with Windows/Active Directory Authentication

I am using a module so that I can call public subroutines and functions, and reference variables, without having to instantiate a new object to access them on each page.

Within that module, I have some Public variables that I am using in multiple pages throughout the web application. I've recently realized that the values for these public variables in the module get shared between all users.

THE GOAL:
I want the value for these global variables to be specific to a single user and not shared between all sessions, and I do not want to have to instantiate a new object/class on every page that uses the variable.

THE CATCH:
I don't want to store the value in a client-side variable such as a cookie or session. I want the value to be stored on the SERVER but specific to each client/user.

The only thing I can think to do is setup a global collection/dictionary and store the variables with the authenticated user names, but then I need to have specific functions to get and set the values. While this will work, it requires all the references to these variables on all pages in the application to be updated.

EXAMPLE OF THE PROBLEM:
The below code shows how I am creating the public variable within the module and how the value is being set from one page and used on another. I'd like to continue to use this variable in the same way and share it's value between pages, but the value of the variable needs to NOT be shared between users.

-- MODULE.VB --

```
Public Module MyMod  
    Public myVariable as String = ""  
End Module
```

-- MAINPAGE.VB --

```
  Partial Class _Default  
        Sub Page_Load() Handles MyBase.Load()  
           myVariable = "HELLO WORLD"  
        End Sub  
    End Class
```

-- NEXTPAGE.VB --

```
  Partial Class _Default  
        Sub Page_Load() Handles MyBase.Load()  
           Response.Write(myVariable)  
        End Sub  
    End Class
```

There are a LOT of pages in this application that will need to be manually updated if I have to use my userID-indexed collection solution, so I'm hoping there is a way to simply scope these variables differently or a way to disable the sharing between sessions.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume these variables are static?  Could you please show the actual classes that you have so we can get a better idea of what you are currently doing?  Also, please format your code samples.

Comment: Also, Session is stored server side, not client side - so it is likely the solution to your issue.

Comment: In VB, I can't make a "static" variable inside a public module ("static is not valid on a member variable declaration"). and unfortunately each class is rather large but is simplified above correctly. For this purpose, the only classes that are used represent the codefile for the ASPX page for the web application.

Comment: No, the members of the Module are already static, VB just doesn't use that terminology.

Comment: As an example, one of the variables used will be an array containing boolean values for different security permissions. These must be specific to the user, but shared amongst all pages in the web application. Also, I was under the impression session variables acted like a cookie and saved somewhere on the client-end? If I'm wrong, you are absolutely correct and that's an easy solution... but unfortunately does still require a lot of code review to replace the local variable declarations with session variables.\

Comment: The only thing that is saved on the client side is a session cookie which is used to access all the values stored in session.  Again, I Believe a custom getter/setter would allow you to rewrite the code to be used with session with minimal code changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't indicate whether or not the variables need to be persisted across page round trips or whether they are just used within each page's lifecycle.

If they are not persisted across pages, then perhaps the easiest solution is to have all of your pages inherit from a based page class and then move the values from the module into the base page. This way you won't have to change any variable references, only page inheritance.

If you do want to persist the values, completing the above changes makes it much easier to implement. You can then turn the member variables on the base page into properties and embed your user specific caching and fetching in the getter and setter.

For example, instead of:

```
Public MyVariable As String = ""
```

You would have something like:

```
Public Property MyVariable As String
    Get 
       Return GlobalMyVariableCache(UserNameKey)
    End Get
    Set (Value As String)
       GlobalMyVariableCache(UserNameKey) = Value
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Turning the variables into properties was the step I was missing. Writing the functions for a global variable collection was fairly trivial, and with the use of the property I don't have to change everywhere I am setting/pulling values for the variables. Thanks!

Comment: One note/update, I didn't need to put the properties into a base page class, adding them into the existing module worked just fine.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are coming across is a very common one in web programming.  A Module's members are static - meaning there is one instance of them across the entire AppDomain of your application.  Every user that accesses these will get the same object - you have already learned this.

Your options are exactly what you described.  You could possibly replace the public variable in your module with a property whose getter you write to access a user-specific field in a dictionary (please remember thread safety when writing this getter code).

The much easier solution would be to use the Session.  Session values are stored server-side and are user specific.  The only thing that get's sent client side is the session key, and if you are using .Net authentication, this is likely already getting sent.

Good luck,

Comment: Good feedback here too, tried to +1 but I'm a new user so it wouldn't let me. Thanks!