# Asp.net Session Start How To?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, global-asax

Can somebody please explain why if i (try) to create an instance of a class in session start event i always get the same instance across multiple sessions?
I have several classes, let say Teacher, Student & Doc.
in a public module i have

```
Public Teachers as Teacher  
Public Students as Student  
Public Doc as Documents  

Global.asax  

session start event   
Teachers = new teacher  
Students = new Student  
Doc = new Documents
```

I'd supposed that every time a session starts i'll get a new instance of each class. I don't understand why this is not happening.

Whatever i do, i end up with the same instance. If i open a browser and set a value to any class member, the same value is present in another browser-session. Is Like if instead of a session variable i have an application variable????!!!!
How/where can i declare my objects to be used across the whole site per session?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You might want to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11802850/how-to-get-a-public-variable-in-a-module-to-not-share-value-between-users

Comment: What do these classes do? there might be a better solution like using a `singleton` or `static` (shared in VB I think) class

Comment: Can you share more of your code?  It's not apparent from the limited code sample you provided what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Set Value:

```
Session("Teachers") = New Teachers
```

Get Value:

```
Dim objTeachers As Teachers = CType(Session("Teachers"), Teachers)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not use session start as it is static and therefor will only provide one instance of a class, i would initialize any classes that you need to use in the page load event/method.

If there is data that you do need to persist during session for that specific user use session see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.ASPX